# WSO2 Iterator to request multiple pages from a Workday webservice

Tags: service, proxy, iterator, wso2

This is my SOAP request to WD:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wd:Get_Workers_Request bsvc:version="v28.0">

         <!--Optional:-->
         <wd:Response_Filter>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wd:As_Of_Effective_Date>2017-07-07</wd:As_Of_Effective_Date>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wd:As_Of_Entry_DateTime>2017-07-07</wd:As_Of_Entry_DateTime>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wd:Count>20</wd:Count>
         </wd:Response_Filter>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <wd:Response_Group>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <wd:Include_Personal_Information>true</wd:Include_Personal_Information>
             </wd:Response_Group>
      </wd:Get_Workers_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to extract the Total Pages attribute from the response XML for this request and iterate through and request all pages using a WSO2 proxy service.  Below is the partial SOAP response with the Total pages attribute:

```
         <wd:Response_Results>
            <wd:Total_Results>1</wd:Total_Results>
            <wd:Total_Pages>10</wd:Total_Pages>
            <wd:Page_Results>1</wd:Page_Results>
            <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
         </wd:Response_Results>
```

WSO2 Proxy Service that currently returns the first page, transforms and writes to an AWS S3 bucket.  I need to enhance this to parse the response get the Total Pages attribute from the XML and iterate through and request all subsequent pages and then aggregate the results into a single CSV file.

- 1. How do I extract the wd:Total_Pages and create an iterator
- 2. Increment the SOAP request wd:Page value and perform all steps as shown below in the proxy inSequence?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="DWHumanResourceProxy"
           startOnLoad="true"
           statistics="disable"
           trace="disable"
           transports="https">
       <target>
          <inSequence>
             <sequence key="SecurityHeader_WD_EIP_jjonesAMU3_Seq"/>
             <switch source="$trp:SOAPAction">
                <case regex="&#34;Get_Workers&#34;">
                   <log level="custom">
                      <property name="message" value="Get_Workers matched."/>
                   </log>
                   <call>
                      <endpoint key="WD_HumanResources_AMU3_Address_Endpoint"/>
                   </call>
                   <xslt description="DW Get Workers XSLT"
                         key="gov:trunk/xslt/DW_WD_HR_GetWorkers_All.xsl"/>
                   <property name="messageType"
                             scope="axis2"
                             type="STRING"
                             value="text/plain"/>
                   <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED"
                             scope="axis2"
                             type="STRING"
                             value="true"/>
                   <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                   <property action="remove" name="Content-Encoding" scope="transport"/>
                   <amazons3.init>
                      <accessKeyId></accessKeyId>
                      <secretAccessKey></secretAccessKey>
                      <methodType>PUT</methodType>
                      <contentType>text/plain</contentType>
                      <addCharset>false</addCharset>
                      <host>s3.amazonaws.com</host>
                      <isXAmzDate>true</isXAmzDate>
                      <bucketName></bucketName>
                   </amazons3.init>
                   <amazons3.createObject>
                      <bucketUrl>http://s3.amazonaws.com</bucketUrl>
                      <objectName>WD_GetWorkers_All.csv</objectName>
                   </amazons3.createObject>
                   <log>
                      <property name="Service" value="AWS Connector test Called from GetWorkers..."/>
                   </log>
                </case>
                <default>
                   <log level="custom">
                      <property name="message" value="Invalid Action!"/>
                   </log>
                </default>
             </switch>
             <respond/>
          </inSequence>
          <outSequence>
             <send/>
          </outSequence>
          <faultSequence/>
       </target>
       <publishWSDL key="gov:/trunk/wsdls/workday/com/1.0.0/Workday_Human_Resources_DW.wsdl"/>
       <description/>
    </proxy>
```